# Ruby gem permission denied /var/lib/gems using Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm trying to install Rails using Gem and did the following from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential
sudo apt-get install rubygems
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
gem install rails
```

Then I get the following message:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno:EACCES)
>   Permission denied - /var/lib/gems

I've followed the instruction from [Ubuntu Help Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Intro_Ubuntu_9.04_..._Apache2.2_tested_only) & I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox to run Ubuntu under Windows 7 and have RubyGems v1.8.15.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to prefix the `gem` command with `sudo` because `/var/lib/gems` is owned by `root`. You could also take a look at [RVM](https://rvm.io/) which allows *really* easy installation and management of gems and Ruby versions. Best part, it's all in your home dir!

EDIT: per @AndrewMarshall's comment bellow, rbenv is an alternative to RVM.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Hi I am getting this error while using RVM funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p392@goodsounds
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems

Comment: @Abram: Please post this as a new question and leave me the link.

Comment: I've set `gems`'s permission too 777 at `/var/lib/`. Why should it be a problem now? I am still getting error. I tried `chown`ing it by the current user `pi` and reverting permission back to `755` then it worked but then I got an error at `/usr/local/bin` where I changed the permission to `777` it worked.

Comment: @amar: Because `gem` needs to be able to access `root` owned directories. But don't change the permissions of root owned ***anything***. It's a really bad idea. Just use sudo.

Comment: Yes @Linuxios right. It was just desperation. 

Anyway, I tried RVM(that is how I am using it on my Pi now) and it's so flawless that I curse myself why I was not convinced earlier to use RVM.

Comment: What  if I'm seeing a similar error but in Windows ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178914/error-while-installing-sass-using-gem-in-windows

Comment: @DioPhung: I don't use Windows, so I'm afraid I can't help you, but I hope someone with Windows experience will see your question and be able to answer it!