# Error while installing sass using gem in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, rubygems

I install Ruby 2.3.0 using Chocolatey, then seeing this error

```
gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/tools/ruby23/bin/sass.bat
```

I tried changing the security permission of C:\tools\ruby23 , but it didn't help.
What went wrong ?

Comment: didyou tried to run administrator?

Comment: Yes I did, ran cmd as admin.